# Is it possible to disable an entry in QComboBox

Tags: c++, qt

I am currently adding items to Qcombobox as such

```
ui.comboBox->addItem("SomeItemA");
ui.comboBox->addItem("SomeItemB");
```

I wanted to know if there was a way to disable items in Qcombobox such that they are not selectable. I am using Qt5

Comment: I don't know of a way to do this directly, but I do have a way to fake it -- if Dmitry's answer doesn't work, let me know and I will post some code.

Comment: Dmitrys answer did the trick

Comment: Cool, I may have to revisit my code, since it could be a lot simpler than it is :)

Comment: Is is helpful to use Qt MVC everywhere, where it's possible. QStandardDataModel, QDataWidgetMapper do a lot of work.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try

```
qobject_cast< QStandardItemModel * >( ui.comboBox->model() )->item( 0 )->setEnabled( false )
```

Comment: This should show checking return value of `qobject_cast`, and at the very least assert with useful error message in case the model isn't `QStandardItemModel`.

Comment: @hyde ofc, it just a sample that demonstrates idea. If you know, what is qobject_cast and what is arrays (OutOfRange) then there will be no problems.